# Send Angular $http.delete with body

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

In my Angular app, I need to send an `$http.delete` request this route `/projects/:id/activityTypes` (note it does not end with an activity type id) passing a body with the following format:

```
[{"id": 2}]
```

This is to allow batch delete operations by sending multiple objects within the array.

Testing the route above with Rest Web Service Client I get a `200, OK` status so the route is already implemented and working fine, I just need to implement it in my Angular app.

Now, [I've checked this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29791003/angular-http-delete-request-with-body) which has a very similar question and learned that angular's `$http.delete` does not send a body in the request by default, but that:

> [it] does allow us to supply a config object as the second parameter,
>   through which we can get access to the 'data' property.

So I tried what was suggested and sent a config object in my request:

```
return $http.delete('projects/' + projectID + '/activityTypes', {data: [{id: 2}]})
```

However, it does not work. It seems that although I am sending this config object, I am still not sending a body.

How can I *actually* pass a body to my `$http.delete` route?

**EDIT:** Here is what the server is logging when I send the `$http.delete` request above:

[image]

The data appears to have been sent, but I get this console error which I don't get when using the Rest Client:

```
Object {data: "Json not valid to remove activity type from Project", status: 400, config: Object, statusText: "Bad Request"}
```

Comment: It would be much easier to use `$http.post` to call this bulk delete route and pass your data there.

Comment: I can send a delete within a post?

Comment: your log shows body , not sure why you say it doesn't. Sounds more like a problem in how you are handling it server side

Comment: @Tiago There is nothing about your server side application so I can only assume that it might be RoR and then just change your route to be a `post` instead of `delete` there.

Comment: @charlietfl I'm not sure either, I should probably edit that out. So this is a server side parsing issue? Why does it give a 200 when I test with my Rest Client though?

Comment: 200 just means the request status.... it doesn't mean logic at server did what it was supposed to

Comment: I understand that but if I get 200 on my Rest Client and 400 when actually using the application, then it must mean something is wrong with my code, correct? I must be sending a badly formatted JSON. Is the data key of the config object I'm passing appended to the request body?

Comment: Depends how your rest is set up and is nothing we can tell from angular or any other client side code

Comment: By using that config object as stated on my question: `{data: [{id: 2}]}`, is this data information appended to the body of the http request?

Answer (score 6):

try this:

```
$http({
            method: 'DELETE',
            url: 'projects/' + projectID + '/activityTypes',
            data: [{id: 2}]},
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

@Renato's approach will work, but so would the `$http.delete(...)` approach, with a little tweaking.  By including the `data` element in the request options, you do pass along data to the server, and you can confirm this in your Developer's Console.  However, without the appropriate Content-Type, your server may likely ignore it.

The following should work:

```
return $http.delete('projects/' + projectID + '/activityTypes', {data: [{id: 2}], headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'}})
```

Credit goes to @Harshit Anand for his [on another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37796227/body-is-empty-when-parsing-delete-request-with-express-and-body-parser).