# AngularJS $http.delete Request with Body and Headers

Tags: angularjs, http, http-delete

Hey so for POST/PUT requests simply doing

```
$http.post(url, body, headers)
```

worked fine

But with DELETE it gets my body, but completely ignores my headers...

```
$http.delete(url, body, headers)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The documentation is terrible, with v1.3.20 you need to do:

$http.delete(url, {data: {...}, headers: {...}})

... which is completely different than post/put for some reason.

Answer (score 6):

The two key elements to include in your options are the `data` an `Content-Type` (as part of your `headers` object).  Your request would look something like:

```
$http.delete(url, {data: {...}, headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'}})
```

Credit goes to @Harshit Anand for his [on another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37796227/body-is-empty-when-parsing-delete-request-with-express-and-body-parser).

Comment: Great! @astangelo