# nestjs http method delete method send body data arrive empty

Tags: http, nestjs

I build nestjs project with microservices and I'm trying to send body data from HTTP method "delete" and get the data from req.body.
that data is arrive empty.

nestjs project

```
  await this.httpServiceInstance
    .delete(`deleteData`, {
    data,
    })
```

microservice project

routes

```
  app.delete("/deleteData", endpoint(deleteData));
```

function deleteData

```
        module.exports = async (req) => { console.log(req.body) /* more code*/ }
```

it's print empty object {}

Comment: There could be multiple reasons for it, could you please monitor network on the server or container and check if it is even reaching to the server? If it is, may be something on you server app could be the reason may be deserialization in wrong format.

Comment: Is it possible that the issue would be related to axios? https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/3220

Comment: Can you please add both server and client code?

Comment: that's part of my code. from client I use postman to simulate.. other request works good. only delete method with body not accept the body in microservice

Comment: Can you state the version you are using? In addition, what is the data type of `this.httpServiceInstance`?

Comment: The `delete` method could be sending the request with the wrong headers ?
Similar to this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37796227/body-is-empty-when-parsing-delete-request-with-express-and-body-parser

Comment: @ggordon httpServiceInstance is type of HttpService from @nestjs/common

Answer (score 1):

Please set `$httpProvider` in your config this way:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.delete = { "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8" };
```

and then call `delete` request:

```
await this.httpServiceInstance
.delete(`xxxxx`, {
data,
})
```

Comment: Hi, I added this to the request but it's still not working. in microservice it's still empty

Comment: @Manspof this should work. Can you please provide me with a full project source code, so that I can reproduce your problem and try to help.

Comment: can we make private chat and I share to you?

Comment: @Manspof No, it should be publically available here, so that other potential users benefit from the answer

Comment: @Manspof you don't have to send your own full source code. Just make a dummy project with minimum required code for reproducing purpose only

Comment: I updated my question with demo code. let me know if you have question

Answer (score -1):

I think you're using `express`, although I don't see it explicitly stated. It needs a body parser, for example:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// parse body as JSON, puts object into req.body
app.use(express.json());

app.route('/deleteData')
.all((req, res) => {
    console.log(req.method, req.body);
    res.json(req.body);
});

app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Server started on port: ' + port);
});
```

Start the server, then test:

```
curl -X DELETE --data '{"foo": "bar"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://localhost:3000/deleteData
```

Server console shows: `DELETE { foo: 'bar' }`, returns `{"foo":"bar"}` to the client.